# C++ Set или List

Tags: stl, c++

Здравствуйте, для представления смежности графа лучше использовать массив сетов или листов?
Чем вообще отличается изнутри сет от листа.Спасибо

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440682/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Как бы смешно это не звучало, но практика показывает, что для представления графа в виде *adjacency lists* лучше всего подходит `std::vector`, а не `std::list`.
2. В использовании `std::set` обычно нет необходимости.
3. Вот [выдержка из англоязычного StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5440803/488443):

   > ... в 90% случаев `std::vector` будет наилучшим выбором. Да, связный список выглядит привлекательнее в подавляющем большинстве случаев, поскольку порядок элементов для него (как правило) несущественен. Иными словами, добавляемые элементы помещаются в конец буфера-контейнера *[вне зависимости от места их вставки — прим. пер.]*, а удаляемый элемент предварительно обменивается местами с конечным, так что вставка и удаление затрагивают только элемент в конце этого буфера.
   >
   > Вектор, в свою очередь, копирует свои элементы при каждом расширении своего буфера, однако на практике это несущественно. Экспонециальный рост гарантирует, что среднее количество копирований стремится к некоторой константе, как правило трём или около того.
   >
   > Даже если копирование действительно является для вас проблемой (к примеру, элементы имеют большой размер), я всё равно не перешёл бы на связный список. Вместо этого я использовал бы `std::deque`. Это, по сути, вектор указателей на блоки с элементами. Он редко копирует что-либо при расширении, а если и копирует, то только эти указатели, но не сами элементы. Однако вектор является всё же более предпочтительным выбором, пока вам не требуются возможности, присущие именно деку (вставка в любой из концов и удаление из них); но даже дек предпочтительнее, чем список. Иными словами, сначала `std::vector`, потом `std::deque` и только в самом конце `std::list`.

Comment: Насчет использования set можно спорить. Зависит от конкретных алгоритмов работы с графом.

Comment: В + set то что он не будет дублировать вершины.

Comment: @avp, плюсую, и от алгоритмов, и даже от особенностей класса графов, рассматриваемых в задаче (если, конечно, это не просто учебное задание).

Answer (score 3):

Относительно устройства этих контейнеров. List реализуется как двусвязный список. Set представляет собой автоматически  отсортировнный массив элементов. Обычно он реализуется в виде бинарных деревьев, что обеспечивает быстрый поиск нужного элемента. Кроме того, set не допускает дублирования элементов (в отличие от multiset). Более подробно - Джосаттис "С++. Стандартная библиотека."

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от желаемого. Обход смежных вершин на списке выполнится не медленнее чем в set или в вектор, зато сэкономит и память, и время в случае разряженного графа.

Опрос "есть ли ребро между вершинами А и Б" на векторе выполнится за постоянное время, на сете за логарифм, на списке линейно.